# Multiple failed attempts to open a text file in C++

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, fstream

I have been spending the past hour trying to figure out how to display a text document programmatically in c++.

The following is the simple main.cpp code, in which I create a directory "Profiles", and another directory "TestProfile" inside. In Profiles/TestProfile I create a "TestFile" and write "Test data" into it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include "Profile.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    ofstream fs;
    
    mkdir("/Users/dario/Desktop/Profiles", S_IRWXU);
    mkdir("/Users/dario/Desktop/Profiles/TestProfile", S_IRWXU);
    fs.open("/Users/dario/Desktop/Profiles/TestProfile/TestFile");
      
    fs << "Test data\n";
    
   
    string path = "/Users/dario/Desktop/Profiles/TestProfile/TestFile";
    system(path.c_str());

    
    return 0;
}
```

Everything up until line 30 works as expected. The directories are there, and "TestFile" is present with data written.
[image: Directories]

There are no errors present when compiling, but ./a.out gives me a permission denied

```
darios-mbp:FMES dario$ g++ -std=c++2a main.cpp 
darios-mbp:FMES dario$ ./a.out 
sh: /Users/dario/Desktop/Profiles/TestProfile/TestFile: Permission denied
```

I tried a few approaches.

First, I checked the permissions of the text file using ls -l,
it returned -rw-r--r--, so I used chmod 755. After that, the file permissions said -rwxr-xr-x. When running the same code, ./a.out returned no permission denied and it seems like it worked, but the text file was not opened.

Secondly, after the first approach didn't work, I deleted the directories and ./a.out to recreate the original permission denied issue.

I was getting permission denied as before, and this time I tried changing the ownership or the directory.

```
sh: /Users/dario/Desktop/Profiles/TestProfile/TestFile: Permission denied
darios-mbp:FMES dario$ chown -R $USER  
/Users/dario/Desktop/Profiles/TestProfile/TestFile
darios-mbp:
```

The command worked, but running the code still did nothing despite no errors.

I tried chmod 755, but again no file was opened.

On previous attempts to fix this issue, after changing the ownership the same way I just explained, I even had an error where it was trying to run the first word of the textfile as a command

```
Line 1: Test: command not found
```

Although I was not able to recreate that while writing this.

Perhaps I am doing something completely wrong, but I looked as much as I could for solutions online before writing this post. None of them seemed to work. Perhaps my situation is unique in some way and someone here could help point me in the right direction. I apologize in advance if my post is in any way not to standard (if so, please let me know how I can improve questions for next time).h

I am running the code on xcode

**EDIT**

Thanks to @Codo for the answer, the following edit did what I was looking for

```
string path = "/Users/dario/Desktop/Profiles/TestProfile/TestFile";
string cmd = "open -a TextEdit  ";
system(cmd.c_str());
```

Comment: How do you expect "Test data" to be a valid system command? You need a sheebang line at the beginning of the file, denoting if it is a shell skript or python code or what ever. And "Test data" wont be a recognized command anyway...

Comment: Are you perhaps assuming that executing a file is the same as double-clicking it in the Finder? It isn't.

Comment: I tried to help debug your program, by copying it into my IDE.  Unfortunately, my IDE does not have the ability to extract code from images.  No code posted as text == no help.

Comment: @WolfgangRoth I am not trying to execute "Test data". I was probably not clear of my question. I am just trying to open "TestFile" the same way you would open it by double-clicking on the file or running "open .." in terminal. I was under the impression that system() would be able to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you want to open the created file with an appropriate application. Let's assume the file is `/dir/file`.

To open a file from the command line / terminal, you would run:

```
open /dir/file
```

Or, if you want a specific applications:

```
open -a TextEdit /dir/file
```

Also see [The macOS open Command](https://scriptingosx.com/2017/02/the-macos-open-command/).

If you just run:

```
/dir/file
```

you would *execute* the file. That's probably not what you intended. And execution is only possible if the file meets certain criteria like execution rights and in the case of a shell script an appropriate header.

In C++, the `system()` function executes a command that would be valid on the command line (in the terminal).

Thus, to fix your program, change the line with `system()` to:

```
string cmd = "open -a TextEdit ";
cmd += path;
system(cmd.c_str());
```

And for your next question: Paste code as text, not as image: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/413337)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. I feel dumb but I guess i didn't look in to what exactly "system()" does. I'm pretty new to c++.

Comment: And thanks for the suggestions on how to improve my questions. I will edit the pictures into code text.